Create event in one calendar, add to another calendar, and mark it as going and send invites using Google Apps Script
I have two calendars: my main one and a second one. I am creating an event in the second one and inviting myself so it shows up on the main one. I am also inviting other addresses.
But:

On my main one calendar, it shows up as not going. I want to mark it as going.
It does not send invites to anyone

I tried to find the event on the main one calendar but there is some kind of timing issue because it takes a few moments for the event to show up on main one so I can't find it to accept it.
I know I could add a delay but that seems kludgy. And that still doesn't solve the problem of invites not getting sent.
Below code shows what I am talking about:
function doIt() {
  var CALENDAR_HOME = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var CALENDAR_TEST = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarsByName("test")[0];

  var startTime = new Date();
  var endTime = new Date();
  endTime.setTime(startTime.getTime() + (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

  var newEventSeries = CALENDAR_TEST.createEventSeries(
    "this is a test for creating events",
    startTime,
    endTime,
    CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule(),
    {
      "guests": `${CALENDAR_HOME.getId()}, anotherUser@gmail.com`,
      "sendInvites": true,
      "location": "here"
    }
  );

  Logger.log(CALENDAR_HOME.getEventSeriesById(newEventSeries.getId())); // logs null

  Logger.log(CALENDAR_HOME.getEvents(
    new Date(1900, 0, 1),
    new Date(3000, 0, 1),
    {
      "search": "this is a test for creating events"
    }
  ).length); // logs 0
}

In this screenshot you can see how it creates the event in the main one calendar but it isn't accepted/going.


Creating a Series Event, Inviting a Calendar You have access with and Mark it as Going(YES)
I created a sample script that you can use as a reference. The script was actually good and was really valid. However I notice that this part of the code is introducing some fluky results.
"guests": `*${CALENDAR_HOME.getId()*}, anotherUser@gmail.com"

with the series of tests I created I suggest that you provide the email to the guest, instead of accessing an object properties. This should solve your invite issues.
Sample Script:
function createSeriesEvents() {
    //var CALENDAR_HOME = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar(); // I removed this instead
    var cguest = ["myemail@sample.com, anotheremail@sample.com"]
    var calendarM = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
    var startTime = new Date();
    var endTime = new Date();
    endTime.setTime(startTime.getTime() + (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(5);
    var option = {
        "guests": cguest[0],
        "sendInvites": true,
    }

    var nSeries = calendarM.createEventSeries("Going Create Event", startTime, endTime, recurrence, option).getId();
    updateMyStatus(nSeries);
    console.log("Success")
}

function updateMyStatus(eventSID) {
    var mainC = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("sample@sample.com");
    var event = mainC.getEventSeriesById(eventSID);

    event.setMyStatus(CalendarApp.GuestStatus.YES)
}

Screenshot of the Result:

Reference:
Calendar EventSeries
SetMyStatus()

This works because you're doing everything in the default/main calendar. I am creating the event in a second (non default/main) calendar.
